# NPM and Yarn cant install anything

Tags: node.js, npm-install, yarnpkg

**I tried every single Stackoverflow answer**. I'm super new to Node and I installed Node v12.16.2 on my Windows 10. It had NPM v 6.14.4. When I install anything NPM showed

```
rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session c0117abdee5b38c1
npm ERR! code E404 
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react
```

I did quite a lot fixes reading stackoverflow, I reinstalled node, but still i got no change in the error.
I installed yarn using their installer. Installing anything in Yarn shows,

```
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/react: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: registry.npmjs.org. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:www.google.com".
```

Some Stackoverflow answers say its some DNS entry being cached or something. I have no clue what to do. If nothing works, is there a way to install packages without using NPM.( like copying files from another computer )

Comment: Can you share your `.npmrc` content? - you can get the content via `npm config get registry` as well.

Comment: My `.npmrc` file is blank. But `npm config get registry` returns `http://registry.npmjs.org/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at my `yarn config list`. It had a lot more than what it needed with many proxy entries, strict-ssl stuff and many more. I deleted everything and started adding whats needed. And now I'm able to install again. Here's my `yarn config list`:

```
yarn config v1.22.4
info yarn config
{
  'version-tag-prefix': 'v',
  'version-git-tag': true,
  'version-commit-hooks': true,
  'version-git-sign': false,
  'version-git-message': 'v%s',
  'init-version': '1.0.0',
  'init-license': 'MIT',
  'save-prefix': '^',
  'bin-links': true,
  'ignore-scripts': false,
  'ignore-optional': false,
  registry: 'https://registry.yarnpkg.com',
  'strict-ssl': true,
  'user-agent': 'yarn/1.22.4 npm/? node/v12.16.2 win32 x64'
}
info npm config
{
  registry: 'https://registry.npmjs.org/'
}
```

Comment: This worked! My `registry` was not set to  `'https://registry.npmjs.org/'`. I did so using `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Answer (score 1):

### **How to clear the local DNS cache in Windows?**

You can flush your local DNS cache in Windows by following these easy steps:

**Windows 7:**

Open Start menu

Click Run

Type `cmd` and press enter

In the Command Prompt type `ipconfig /flushdns` and press Enter

**Windows 8, 10:**

On your keyboard, press Win+X to open the WinX Menu

Right-click Command Prompt and select Run as Administrator

Run this command `ipconfig /flushdns` and press Enter

Source : https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_clear_the_local_dns_cache_in_windows/